# How do I fix a nav menu (secondary menu) in place whilst scrolling down through content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a main menu on my page and then I have another menu below the header section, used to categorize different sections of this page. I would like to fix this secondary in place, so that when I scroll, it stays in place, (top of the page. The problem is that my main menu is also already fixed to the top of he page, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

I've tried fixing it in place, but the text scrolls through and if i fix it to the top of page, it disappears.

```
 <div class="culmn">
            <!--Home page style-->


            <nav class="navbar navbar-default bootsnav navbar-fixed">
                <div class="navbar-top bg-grey fix">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-6" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
                                <div class="navbar-callus text-left sm-text-center">
                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li><a href="tel:0878209100"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call us: 087 820 9100</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="mailto:sales@urs.co.za"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact us: sales@urs.co.za</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>





                    <!-- Start Header Navigation -->
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                      <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/URS-Logo.png" alt="" width="150" class="logo"></a>


                    </div>
                    <!-- End Header Navigation -->

                    <!-- navbar menu -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">

                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                  
                            <li><a href="our-story.html">Our Story</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="solutions" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Solutions</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
         <li><a href="pos">Point of sale (POS)</a></li>
         <li><a href="reporting">Business Intelligence &amp; Reporting </a></li>         
         <li><a href="solutions#Integrations">Integrations</a></li>
         <li><a href="solutions#DM">Data Management</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="customers.html">Our Customers</a></li>            
                             <li><a href="whats-new.html">What's New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                                   </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
</div>
</nav>

    <!--Home Sections-->        
    <section id="home" class="home bg-black fix" style="background-image:url('assets/images/Man-on-pc-using-business-intelligence.jpg')">

  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="main_home text-center home-main-text">
          <div class="col-md-12" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
              <div class="hello_slid">
                                    <div class="slid_item">
                                        <div class="home_text ">
                                             <h2 class="text-white">Enhance your reporting experience</h2>                    
                                                <h5 class="text-white">Retail Intelligence is our business intelligence software designed to enhance your reporting experience.The intention is to intelligently display what is important to your business so that you can save time and focus on what's important to you.</h5>
                                    </div> 
    <div class="home_btns m-top-40">                                
                            <a class="btn btn-primary m-top-20" onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('mailto:sales@urs.co.za');"
                            href="mailto:sales@urs.co.za?subject=More info on Retail Intelligence please!">Get in touch to arrange a free demo &gt;</a> 

                        </div>
                    </div>              
                 </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </section>

      <section id="Retail Intelilgence">        
      <div class="roomy-40">
       <h2 style="text-align:center">Gain valuable insights and make better 
       business decisions with <strong><br>Retail Intelligence </strong></h2>


  <div class="urs-bar urs-dark-gray">
  <div class="urs-wrap">
    <button class="urs-bar-item urs-button tablink urs-red" onclick="openCity(event,'Overview')">Overview</button>
    <button class="urs-bar-item urs-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Sales')">Sales</button>
    <button class="urs-bar-item urs-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Customers')">Customers</button>
    <button class="urs-bar-item urs-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Staff')">Staff</button>
    <button class="urs-bar-item urs-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Inventory')">Inventory</button>
    <button class="urs-bar-item urs-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Risk')">Risk</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I'm expecting the menu to be fixed below the main menu. Is that possible?

Comment: www.urs.co.za/test/pos to see live page.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap?

Comment: @HowardE v3.3.7